# How to migrate existing table using Django and Python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I need one help. I have one existing mysql table in my localhost database and I need it to migrate using Django and Python. Here is my code:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangotest',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I am giving my table structure below.

Person:

```
id    name  phone  age
```

models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Actually I am new to Django and Python and here I need to know command which can migrate the existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to create migrations you need to use this command -

```
   python manage.py makemigrations
```

the above command will create a file inside the migrations folder in your app directory and
to create/update table using the migration file in the database

```
  python manage.py migrate
```

The above command will create/update a table in your DB.

[Django Migration Docmentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/)

Let me know, if this is what you want!

Comment: @satya , is this what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually I have one existing table in my DB. I need to migrate that.

Comment: See my post .I want to say I have created one table in `localhost/phpmyadmin` and I need to use that in my app.Actually I am new to `Django and Python` and I am making one `crud` application.

Comment: Actually I run `python manage.py sql crud` and it gave me `Unknown command: 'sql'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.`.

Comment: if you have created a table already in you db (e.g mysql) , then you don't need to run steps I mentioned above unless you need to update some columns etc , and also you have added table schema in models.py , I think it would be sufficient , you just start using it without any migrations .

Comment: @satya , please upvote my answer if you find it useful thanks .

Answer (score 1):

In reference to akhilsp, I did not have to worry about table names using the _ format. Using the inspectdb command returned a Meta data for whatever the current table name is that I used in my model.

```
class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'malware'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inspectdb` command from the shell.

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

This will print models corresponding to the current database structure. You copy the required model, make changes like adding validations, and then add other models.

`python manage.py makemigrations` will create migrations, and

`python manage.py migrate` will apply those migrations.

N.B: Your table name should be in the format "appname_modelname" where appname is name for django app name (not project name).

Answer (score 0):

Add [`--fake`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) option to migrate command:

> --fake
>
> Tells Django to mark the migrations as having been applied or unapplied, **but without actually running the SQL to change your
>   database schema**.
>
> This is intended for advanced users to manipulate the current
>   migration state directly if they’re manually applying changes; be
>   warned that using --fake runs the risk of putting the migration state
>   table into a state where manual recovery will be needed to make
>   migrations run correctly.

If you just start django project and didn't have initial migration: comment your `Person` model, make initial migration, apply it, uncomment `Person`, make migration for `Person` and at last migrate `Person` with `--fake` option.